# KafkaException: No method found for class java.lang.String

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm trying to use Spring Kafak in a very very simple project, but I get an error when I receive a String message.
The Spring Boot version is 2.2.6.RELEASE.
This is the content of my application.yml (according to official Spring Boot documentation, it should be enough):

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      group-id: group-id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
```

This is the listener class:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@KafkaListener(topics = KafkaSampleApplication.TOPIC)
public class MessageReceiver {
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> cr) throws Exception {
        log.info(String.format("$$ -> Consumed Message -> %s", cr.toString()));
    }
}
```

and this is the error:

```
2020-04-11 11:21:04.265  INFO 11032 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : group-id: partitions assigned: [claudiotopic01-0]
2020-04-11 11:21:04.296 ERROR 11032 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = claudiotopic01, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 3, CreateTime = 1586595579264, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 5, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = ciao4)

org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: No method found for class java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1790) [spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1779) [spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1692) [spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1618) [spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1521) [spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1262) [spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1009) [spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:929) [spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: No method found for class java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.getHandlerForPayload(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:170) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.getMethodNameFor(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:279) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.getMethodAsString(HandlerAdapter.java:67) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:346) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:86) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1741) [spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1724) [spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1679) [spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

This is the output of the Consumer configuration on start-up:

```
020-04-11 11:21:04.218[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11032[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = group-id
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@KafkaListener` goes on the method, not the class, unless you want to [use a multi-method listener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#class-level-kafkalistener), in which case you need `@KafkaHandler` on the methods.